# Is there a TSO command written in REXX or CLIST that can determine WHO has enqueued a dataset?

Tags: mainframe, zos, rexx, tso, clist

I need to write a REXX Exec or Clist to identify WHO has enqueued a Dataset and display a user friendly message on an ISPF dialog application.  Due to system configuration issues, the %WHOHAS command is not available.  However I also know that ISPF itself (Option 3.4) has proprietary hooks into the zos mainframe to display the enqueued resource information I need - so the infomation can be obtained. Unfortunately I don't know how to access this data from outside ISPF 3.4 using a REXX Exec or CLIST.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a very simple fix.  Nothing fancy.  If the clist uses CONTROL NOFLUSH it will not abort when the ALLOCation of a dataset fails.  We also have a installed product called TSOPLUS that will format a message to the terminal identifying who has allocated a dataset when the allocation fails.  By turning off FLUSH and then systrapping the TSOPLUS message, I was able to extract the information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

On first reading I thought this would be a pretty simple thing to
dig up. Not quite!

Under ISPF you can get a panel to display who is holding a dataset
by typing the following on the command line:

> TSO ISRDDN ENQ 'Dataset-name'

The ISRDDN command is documented at:
http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/FRAMESET/ispzug50/G.0?ACTION=MATCHES&REQUEST=isrddn&TYPE=FUZZY&SHELF=ispzpm50&DT=20060621022939

Invoking ISRDDN is possible from within a REXX program but I don't
know how to capture the output into a stem variable where you could
parse it out and issue a message. I could not find a command line
interface to ISRDDN that allows capture of the output.

There is another utiltiy at:
http://www.sillysot.com/mvs/index.htm?queryenq.htm
that claims to do this as well, I have never tried it so cannot
comment any further on it.

I Googled your question and it looks like several people have used
the MVS command

> D GRS,RES=(*,dsname)

to determine who is holding
a dataset. However, this requires console access so would not be
appropriate for most users. If console access is allowed, then you could start a console
session under REXX and capture the output fairly easily, see: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg244626.pdf.

One final place to search would be the CBT tapes (freeware for
IBM mainframes). Here you can find several implementations of the WHOHAS
ISPF command.

Sorry, but this is the best I can do.

Comment: This was an interesting response.  I tried issuing the TSO ISRDDN END 'Dataset-name' command and got the response...

"This system is running with SETGRS MODE=STAR.  ENQ information will not be collected from other systems, ENQ displays may not reflect all of the ENQs which are known to GRS."

During the test - the job that held the dataset was not detected.

I believe the %WHOHAS clist also invokes the same command "D GRS,RES=(*,dsname)" so they are clearly related.  

It seems ISPF 3.4 is using an unknown method to access this data.  I'll look some more at your other suggestions. thx

Comment: Just noticed my link to the ISPF ISRDDN documentation was wrong - jsut fixed it.